# SSL doesn't work on Chrome but works on every other browser

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate

A friend of mine (not technical person) moved an API of a web application from azure to liquidweb.  Users with FireFox and Edge are able to see the website just fine.  But users with Chrome get SSL issues .  When I use Chrome to visit the api url `https://api.example.com`, I noticed that the address bar gave an exclamation mark instead of the usual lock icon.  Clicking on the exclamation mark gave the typical `Your site connection is not secure message`.  Again, this is not a problem in FireFox or Edge.

I looked at my friend's IIS settings which are shown here:

[image]

And the details of the certificate are all "green icon" except for `key usage` and `basic constraints` as shown here

[image]
[image]

I personally have other websites hosted on the bluehost.com shared hosting which uses linux, nginx, and let's encrypt ssl that show the same settings for `key usage` and `basic constraints` that don't have the same problem.

What might be wrong with my friend's SSL set up that could be causing issues for Chrome?

---

ADDITIONAL

Here's what I see in Chrome:

[image]

Also, my friend's server uses Windows Server 2016 on build 1607 with IIS version 10.

---

ADDITIONAL 2

FireFox shows that the Subject Alt Name is the same as the Common name.  Screenshot here:

[image]

---

ADDITIONAL 3

Also, here's a verification check from https://sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html

[image]

Comment: can you post exact error message from Chrome?

Comment: OK, updated with an image of what's in Chrome and also mentioned server versions.

Comment: I would check the spelling of web address and if it is resolved to required IP address.

Comment: I pinged the api url and it showing the ip address of our liquidweb server.  Browsers will show 401, 403 or 404 errors until Authorization headers are sent.

Comment: Chrome clearly says that it can't reach the address (404). It is something Chrome-related.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not as concerned about the http response, which changes depending on the endpoint (example if I typed /api/Advertise, then I get a 401 response).  I just have to figure out why the SSL isn't recognized.  Let me know if other ideas!  I wonder if disable SNI will do anything I would have to try that at night.

Comment: IIS and Chrome perfectly work with SNI, so unlikely is a problem. Though, I would check if other sites that use SSL are configured to use SNI.

Comment: Is the real URL really top secret? It would be way easier for us to test with the real URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the following IIS settings resolved my issues:

Go to SSL Settings for your app

[image]

Then change the radio option to ignore:

[image]

This answer gives more insight into why this works:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383538/what-is-the-difference-between-requiring-an-ssl-cert-and-accepting-an-ssl-cert

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the domain name is not listed in the "Subject Alternative Name" (SAN) field of the certificate, and it's mandatory since Chrome 58 :
https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7391219?hl=en

Ensure that the domain name is listed in the Subject Alternative Name, even if the Subject Name is correct.

Or you are using a [revoked Let's Encrypt certificate](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/revoking-certain-certificates-on-march-4/114864), check here: https://checkhost.unboundtest.com/

Comment: I updated my question to confirm that FireFox shows the Common Name is the same as the Subject Alt Name.  Let me know if I made a mistake?

Comment: I see that it's a Let's Encrypt certificate, I updated my answer because Let's Encrypt had to revoke a lot of certificates recently

Comment: Ok checking now to see

Comment: I tried the unboundtest.com and it told me `The certificate currently available on ......com is OK. It is not one of the certificates affected by the Let's Encrypt CAA rechecking problem. `